# Is "es" always a dummy subject rather than a real subject when "verschlagen" means "bring"?

Tags: usage

> Was meinst du, wohin es uns diesmal **verschlagen** wird?

When the verb "verschlagen" has the meaning of "bring", I wonder if the subject "es" always acts as a placeholder subject "it" with no real meaning -- in order to express the idea of "(someone) ends up (somewhere)"?

Or is it possible for a real subject to be used there, too?

Comment: Maybe "Was meinst du, wohin das Schicksal uns diesmal verschlagen wird?"

Comment: http://www.wissen.de/rechtschreibung/verschlagen

Comment: http://www.frm-united.com/uploads/media/FRM_Magazin_Deutsch_2-2009.pdf   "Irgendwann hat mich das Leben hierher verschlagen..."

Comment: "das Geld hat mich hierher verschlagen" https://books.google.at/books?id=vfnUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=hierher+verschlagen&source=bl&ots=mhJ_BK4PWG&sig=bblzAQrQx8t8OVNVZt_oMS2-bM8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2vq_NmPbTAhUCIsAKHbpKCb84ChDoAQgqMAI#v=onepage&q=hierher%20verschlagen&f=false

Comment: "die Umleitung hat uns nach links verschlagen"  http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/dorthin+verschlagen.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A real subject can be used there but the subject is an abstract term

From the  [Neue Zürcher Zeitung, 2009-11-01, "Ossis in der Schweiz"](https://www.nzz.ch/ossis-in-der-schweiz-1.3953357)

> Der Fall der Berliner Mauer vor 20 Jahren änderte den Lauf der Weltgeschichte und Millionen von Biografien. Auch in der Schweiz leben heute viele Menschen, die in der DDR aufgewachsen sind. Vier erzählen, wie **die Liebe, die Arbeit und die Vorsehung** sie hierher **verschlagen** haben. Von Christoph Plate

From [a letter of Johann Ernst Lüdeke to Immanuel Kant, 30th December 1797](https://korpora.zim.uni-duisburg-essen.de/kant/aa12/227.html)

> Hätte mich **die Vorsehung** in die Schriftsteller Welt **verschlagen** ich stehe 
>   nicht dafür daß ich Sie mit einer Menge Zueignungs Schriften geqvälet
>   hätte und mir dadurch ein gewißes Ansehen zu erdediciren gesucht.

From [an interview with Daniel Cohn-Bendit in 
FRM, Das Magazin über die Metropolregion FrankfurtRheinMain, Herbst 2009,p 30](http://www.frm-united.com/uploads/media/FRM_Magazin_Deutsch_2-2009.pdf)

> Irgendwann hat mich **das Leben** hierher **verschlagen**, es hat mir hier gefallen, ich habe mich hier verliebt und ich lebe hier.

[Die Wiedergänger - Ein Bericht aus dem 18. Jahrhundert, Roman
von Christian Baier
Luzifer-Verlag, 2016, p 27](https://books.google.at/books?id=V8kDDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=schicksal++verschlagen&source=bl&ots=ozmuZdP86Z&sig=Mo8W7T0LfMgCYe4veo1s71Q2GZM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLnobAlfbTAhWTHsAKHUcIBn4Q6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=schicksal%20%20verschlagen&f=false)

> Manche Stunden verbrachte er über der Landkarte und starrte voll Ingimm auf die Ödnis, in die ihn **ein ungerechtes Schicksal verschlagen** hatte.

https://www.hermann-hesse.de/files/pdfs/de_hodjak.pdf

[Franz Hodjak,
Der Junge in der Nagold,
Mai bis August 1998](https://www.hermann-hesse.de/files/pdfs/de_hodjak.pdf)
Entstanden während des Hermann-Hesse-Stipendiums in Calw

> "Eine Ortschaft weiter
>   gibt es eine Umleitung, doch dann kommt eine Kreuzung, an der es kein Schild gibt. Er hält den Bus an. Kennt
>   sich jemand hier aus, ruft er. Am Morgen, sagt er, gab es diese Umleitung noch nicht. Im Bus bin nur noch ich,
>   der sich natürlich nicht auskennt, Igor, sage ich, **die Umleitung** hat uns nach links **verschlagen**, also müssen
>   wir nach rechts abbiegen, um wieder auf die Bundesstraße 295 zu kommen. Logisch, lacht Igor."

[Besenkammer mit Bett: 
Das Schicksal einer illegalen Hausangestellten in Lateinamerika,
Eva Karnofsky,
Culture Books Verlag, 2013](https://books.google.at/books?id=vfnUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=hierher+verschlagen&source=bl&ots=mhJ_BK4PWG&sig=bblzAQrQx8t8OVNVZt_oMS2-bM8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2vq_NmPbTAhUCIsAKHbpKCb84ChDoAQgqMAI#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> "Was hat Sie denn hierher verschlagen? Düngemittel verkaufen, ist das nicht ziemlich langweilig?"
>   "Geld, meine Liebe. **Das Geld** hat mich hierher **verschlagen**."

Comment: *Schicksal* war auch das erste, das mir eingefallen ist.